# How to push a change to multiple branches

Tags: git, github, gradle

I am working on a fork of a [programming tutorial on Github](https://github.com/udacity/ud843-QuakeReport). I have updated Gradle settings for the master branch. Every time I run `git checkout <existing_branch>` to switch my working directory to a different existing branch, all my Gradle modifications are gone. As I am switching between different branches using `git checkout <branch>` to compile different versions of the project (e.g. lesson-one, lesson-two, lesson-three, etc.), I'd like my Gradle settings to be reflected on all branches so that I don't have to apply those changes on every branch I switch to.
I tried to use the following commands to achieve this, but they failed:

```
git push git push *gradle* lesson-two lesson-one lesson-four starting-point HEAD ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: Do these branches you're working on have a common base? Could you update your gradle on that base and just rebase them all against it?

Comment: @dillius honestly I don't know.

Comment: Is it a requirement of the tutorial that you change your gradle configuration or did you do it to update libraries or the like?

Comment: No it is not a requirement, but it helps use the latest features.

Answer (score 1):

Two options, depending on how comfortable with `git` you are:

The first would be to commit your changes to the gradle file to the `starting-point` branch, then rebase `lesson-one` against it, then `lesson-two` against `lesson-one`, etc. This should work, though it almost looks like his `lesson-one` and `lesson-two` are the same. This assumes you aren't changing it frequently though, or you'd have to keep doing this process each time you did.

Another option would be to make a copy of the gradle file then delete it from the branches, so that git is not tracking it and therefore not changing it when you switch. This is definitely not a good idea when actually writing something, but for the purposes of working a tutorial it could save you some headache for now.